# Gnome3 v40 transparent bar on the buttom

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

I noticed an almost half a centimeter thick transparent bar on the bottom of my screen, which is there on top of every other window, and doesn't seem to be interacting with anything, or the mouse. Also, when I try to take a screenshot, it's not in the screenshot.

This is how it looks like, and I'm not really sure how to start diagnosing it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after talking to Gnome developers [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/4771), turns out one can investigate this the the "looking glass", which you can get by pressing alt+f2, and then `lg`.

Then you click on the target icon on the top left of that panel, and choose the gray transparent area, if it selects it, then it's an application, if not, it's something lower level.

In my case, it selects whatever's behind it, and therefore I guess it's a monitor issue. I'll replace the monitor and hopefully it's fixed.